# How to import another CSS file into CSS file in laravel 5

Tags: css, laravel-5

```
@import url("base.css");
```

This is the method to import general css file into another css file. But this method is not working on laravel 5.

How to import css file into css file in laravel 5?

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: yes, same method is used in laravel also.. no other format is needed. @import url("base.css"); It works!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new CSS file in the public/css folder and then in your main template you include it by doing so :

```
{!! HTML::style('css/your_css_file.css') !!}
```

Comment: i want to include my new css file into my included .css file.. not in the php file.

Comment: why would you want to do that ? why don't you copy what you have into your second css file and paste it in the first one ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't import a CSS file inside another CSS file, you need to include them separately on your blade template. I suppose you have your css files in `/public/css`, then you can include them like this:

```
<link href="{{ asset("/css/firstCSS.min.css")}}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset("/css/secondCSS.min.css")}}" rel="stylesheet">
```